# Why does HTML5 break this code?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I wasn't sure how to ask this question in detail but why does this website not display properly when I set the document to `<!DOCTYPE html>`? I've tried this page on  multiple browsers (ie, firefox, chrome, opera) and they all display incorrectly unless I omit the `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>DotSmasher</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dotSmasher.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="dotSmasher.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="setGameAreaBounds()" onresize="setGameAreaBounds()">
<div id="scoreLabel">Score: 0</div>
<div id="pageTitle">DotSmasher</div>
<div id="gameArea">
    <button id="dot" onClick="detectHit()"></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of how it's suppose to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNTrQ.jpg

Here is a screenshot of how it looks after `<!DOCTYPE html>`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Qtm.jpg

The javascript and CSS codes are below:

```
var score = 0;
var aWidth;
var aHeight;
var timer;
function detectHit() {
score += 1;
scoreLabel.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
}
function setGameAreaBounds() {
if (document.all) {
    aWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    aHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}
else {
    aWidth = innerWidth;
    aHeight = innerHeight;
}
aWidth -= 30;
aHeight -= 95;
document.getElementById("gameArea").style.width = aWidth;
document.getElementById("gameArea").style.height = aHeight;
aWidth -= 74;
aHeight -= 74;
moveDot();

}
function moveDot() {
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * aWidth);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * aHeight);
if (x < 10)
    x = 10;
if (y < 10)
    y = 10;
document.getElementById("dot").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("dot").style.top = y;
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout("moveDot()", 1000);
}


#scoreLabel {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14pt;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
height: 25px;
}

#pageTitle {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 24pt;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000099;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 10px;
height: 25px;
}

#gameArea {
position: absolute;
top: 75px;
left: 10px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#dot {
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
left: 25px;
background-color: #000099;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
}

#stop {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: How is it supposed to look? In what way is it breaking?

Comment: …and what are the files that you do include? Are you getting script errors when changing the doctype?

Comment: any errors from console? any screenshots maybe?

Comment: A missing doctype puts browsers into [quirks mode](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles#Standards_versus_quirks_mode), so they will display [some content differently](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Comment: I placed more info above, the errors I received came from the javascript file even though js works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code you got from a college book is wrong.  I found the book to be [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Tav1LgmTpyoC&pg=PT295&lpg=PT295&dq=dotSmasher.css&source=bl&ots=evv_y6xgr6&sig=Xtg-dcL9fIhnvCJHccCIEpOF6R4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3WyNUr3SHe624AOKsoHoBA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dotSmasher.css&f=false).

At the moment there are at least 2 things wrong.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * aWidth);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * aHeight);
```

Both `aWidth` and `aHeight` are not initialized and therefore you are multiplying by a NULL.  Set these to 1. Like this:

```
var aWidth = 1;
var aHeight = 1;
```

---

Also,

```
document.getElementById("dot").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("dot").style.top = y;
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById("dot").style.left = x + "px";
document.getElementById("dot").style.top = y + "px";
```

They were missing the "px" on the end of the location.

And RobG is right it works without the `DOCTYPE html` because of the quirks mode of the browsers.

Hope this helps.